# XSLT: Populating child node content repeating with parent node elemnts

Tags: xslt

i am trying to transform XML from one form into another form using XSLT.

I have input XML as

```
<Employee>
<Emp>
    <EMPID>123</EMPID>
    <NAME>James</NAME>
    <Sequence>1</Sequence>
    <JOBS>
        <COMPANY>ABC</COMPANY>
        <DESIGNATION>Developer</DESIGNATION>
    </JOBS>
    <JOBS>
        <COMPANY>DEF</COMPANY>
        <DESIGNATION>Tester</DESIGNATION>
    </JOBS>
</Emp>
<Emp>
    <EMPID>456</EMPID>
    <NAME>Clark</NAME>
    <Sequence>2</Sequence>
    <JOBS>
        <COMPANY>GHT</COMPANY>
        <DESIGNATION>QA Lead</DESIGNATION>
    </JOBS>
    <JOBS>
        <COMPANY>Levor</COMPANY>
        <DESIGNATION>Project Lead</DESIGNATION>
    </JOBS>
</Emp>
</Employee>
```

I want to transform into (Desired Output)

```
<Employee>
<Emp>
    <EMPID>123</EMPID>
    <NAME>James</NAME>
    <Sequence>1</Sequence>
    <JOBS>
        <COMPANY>ABC</COMPANY>
        <DESIGNATION>Developer</DESIGNATION>
    </JOBS>
</Emp>
<Emp>
    <EMPID>123</EMPID>
    <NAME>James</NAME>
    <Sequence>1</Sequence>
    <JOBS>
        <COMPANY>DEF</COMPANY>
        <DESIGNATION>Tester</DESIGNATION>
    </JOBS>
</Emp>
<Emp>
    <EMPID>456</EMPID>
    <NAME>Clark</NAME>
    <Sequence>2</Sequence>
    <JOBS>
        <COMPANY>GHT</COMPANY>
        <DESIGNATION>QA Lead</DESIGNATION>
    </JOBS>
</Emp>
<Emp>
    <EMPID>456</EMPID>
    <NAME>Clark</NAME>
    <Sequence>2</Sequence>
    <JOBS>
        <COMPANY>Levor</COMPANY>
        <DESIGNATION>Project Lead</DESIGNATION>
    </JOBS>
</Emp>
</Employee>
```

I have tried this below XSLT and different trails it didnt work, can you please help me to correct this XSLT to get desire output

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="Employee">
    <xsl:element name="Employee">
        <xsl:for-each select="Employee">
            <xsl:sort select="Sequence"/>
            <xsl:element name="Emp">
                <xsl:copy-of select="EMPID"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="NAME"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="Sequence"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="child::JOBS">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="COMPANY"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="DESIGNATION"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please help me?

---

### Added:

Thank you for the quick response, but i forgot to add a case here that JOBS aggregate wont be available for all Employees like below

```
<Employee>
<Emp>
    <EMPID>123</EMPID>
    <NAME>James</NAME>
    <Sequence>1</Sequence>
    <JOBS>
        <COMPANY>ABC</COMPANY>
        <DESIGNATION>Developer</DESIGNATION>
    </JOBS>
    <JOBS>
        <COMPANY>DEF</COMPANY>
        <DESIGNATION>Tester</DESIGNATION>
    </JOBS>
</Emp>
<Emp>
    <EMPID>789</EMPID>
    <NAME>Anderson</NAME>
    <Sequence>3</Sequence>
</Emp>
<Emp>
    <EMPID>456</EMPID>
    <NAME>Clark</NAME>
    <Sequence>2</Sequence>
    <JOBS>
        <COMPANY>GHT</COMPANY>
        <DESIGNATION>QA Lead</DESIGNATION>
    </JOBS>
    <JOBS>
        <COMPANY>Levor</COMPANY>
        <DESIGNATION>Project Lead</DESIGNATION>
    </JOBS>
</Emp>
</Employee>
```

So here Anderson doesn't have emp, and result should be like this

```
<Employee>
<Emp>
    <EMPID>123</EMPID>
    <NAME>James</NAME>
    <Sequence>1</Sequence>
    <JOBS>
        <COMPANY>ABC</COMPANY>
        <DESIGNATION>Developer</DESIGNATION>
    </JOBS>
</Emp>
<Emp>
    <EMPID>123</EMPID>
    <NAME>James</NAME>
    <Sequence>1</Sequence>
    <JOBS>
        <COMPANY>DEF</COMPANY>
        <DESIGNATION>Tester</DESIGNATION>
    </JOBS>
</Emp>
<Emp>
    <EMPID>456</EMPID>
    <NAME>Clark</NAME>
    <Sequence>2</Sequence>
    <JOBS>
        <COMPANY>GHT</COMPANY>
        <DESIGNATION>QA Lead</DESIGNATION>
    </JOBS>
</Emp>
<Emp>
    <EMPID>456</EMPID>
    <NAME>Clark</NAME>
    <Sequence>2</Sequence>
    <JOBS>
        <COMPANY>Levor</COMPANY>
        <DESIGNATION>Project Lead</DESIGNATION>
    </JOBS>
</Emp>
<Emp>
    <EMPID>789</EMPID>
    <NAME>Anderson</NAME>
    <Sequence>3</Sequence>
</Emp>
</Employee>
```

Can you please help me here?

Answer (score 1):

***Edited in response to clarification:***

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Employee">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Emp">
            <xsl:sort select="Sequence"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="Emp[not(JOBS)]">
     <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>     

<xsl:template match="Emp">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="JOBS"/>
</xsl:template>                 

<xsl:template match="JOBS">
    <Emp>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../EMPID | ../NAME | ../Sequence | ."/>
    </Emp>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You could shorten `<xsl:copy-of select="../EMPID | ../NAME | ../Sequence"/>
                <JOBS>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                </JOBS>` to `<xsl:copy-of select="../EMPID | ../NAME | ../Sequence | ."/>`

Comment: Thank you for the response, I missed to add a problem statement which i have edited now. Can you please help me on this?

Comment: Thank you Michael for your turnaround on this problem

Comment: Thank you, this is helped me to answer my question. Can you please help to close this down.